# Why isn't this If Statement executing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

#### Background

I have a Windows Form with the following items:

- `ComboBox`
- `TextBox`
- Two `Buttons`: Forward and Back
- A class - `Items` which holds a `string` `int` and `double` members

---

```
if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 && Items[index].Price > 50.00 )
{
     txtManu.Text = Items[index].Manu;
     txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price);
}
```

When I click the `forward` button on the form I expect all prices over `50.00` to be displayed in the `txtPrice.Text` TextBox but it's displaying all prices instead.

Forward button code snippet:

```
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 && Items[index].Price > 50.00)
{
    index += 1;
    if (index == Items.Length) index = 0;

    txtManu.Text = Items[index].Manu;
}
```

The `ComboBox` has `index[0]` and `index[1]` items: `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0` and `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1`.

The forward button has index 0 and index 1 items too: `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)` and `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)`

Why is the `if` statement not executing?

#### Update

Here is the improved code for the example:

```
Items[0] = new items("Car", 30.00);
Items[1] = new itemss("Cat", 55.00);
Items[2] = new items("Cookie", 59.00);
```

#### ComboBox Code Snippet

```
if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && Items[index].Price > 50.00 )
{ 
    txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price);
} 

###Forward Button
//single combobox
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 && Items[index].Price > 50.00)
{
    index += 1;
}

if (index == Items.Length)
{
    index = 0;
}
txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price);
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code to just a single combobox, a single text box , a single button and a small number of test items, and put your full source code (minus designer code) for this - hopefully it will only be about 30-50 lines or so if you remove all the repeated code and the controls that aren't required to demonstrate the bug.

Comment: Am using else if because its a third statement and has to be else if. ie. if(......) {execute code} else if (......) {execute code}. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Even with the additional code provided, it's still hard to tell what, why, and how you are trying to accomplish things. For example, how is "txtPrice.Text textbox displaying ALL prices" when you always overwrite the text (`txtPrice.Text = "foo"`) and never append to the text (`txtPrice.Text += "foo"`)? What relationship does `index` have to `comboBox1.SelectedIndex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check step by step with the debugger?  I think there is an IndexOutBounds exception happening before the if.  I would probably put a try catch on that block and see if you are getting an exception there.

Comment: Yes I have checked debugger no errors or anything! Weird! Although it doesnt go to next item when I click forward button?? :(

Comment: The comment by Akibo and the "accepted answer" status sort of conflict with each other. Is this solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be incrementing that index too early. You check the value of `Items[index]`, but then you increase index before using the value in `Items[index]`. So you are getting in reality: `Items[index+1]`

But in general I'm pretty confused by your question. Can you possibly post some more code and a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Yes I am incrementing the index to be able to move to next item. OR is this a problem? hmmm?

Comment: Okay so your saying it should be this instead:
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 && Items[index].Price > 50.00)
        {
            if (index == Items.Length) index = 0;
            index += 1;

            txtManu.Text = Items[index].Manu;
          }

Comment: Or you mean this way:  
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 && Items[index].Price > 50.00)
{
txtManu.Text = Items[index].Manu;
txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price);

index += 1;
if (index == Items.Length) index = 0;
}

Comment: Sample data:
Test items:
Items[0] = new items(”Car”, 30.00);
Items[1] = new items(”Cat”, 55.00);
Items[2] = new items(”Cookie”, 59.00);

The combobox:
if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && Items[index].Price > 50.00 )
{ txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price); }

The forward button:
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && Items[index].Price > 50.00)
{ index += 1;
if (index == Items.Length)
index = 0; txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(Items[index].Price); }

txtPrice { //’single textbox’ }